# store the generated output into variables in shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

How to store the output generated by a  curl request into variables

```
m=$(curl  -b cookiez.txt -L http://bmcassistant.org/webac/Department/Student/CurrentSemesterDetails.aspx?|grep -o 'href=.*>.*%' | grep -o '>.*%'|sed 's/>//') 

echo $m>>attendance.txt
```

Output of attendance.txt

> 10% 80% 50% 100%

I want to store these numbers into variables like m,n,o,p
So i can call it later in shell script by referencing them by $m,$n,$o,$p

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  read -a arr <<< $line
  echo ${arr[@]}
done < "attendance.txt"
```

Change the @ for the different values.

Instead of reading the txt file again, as you have `$m` which has the string, you can simply do this:

```
read -a arr <<< $m
```

Comment: @JohnsSimon If it solved your problem, kindly accept the answer.